# How to get an n+2 column in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectors

> `function dy = SIR(t,y)`
>
> `n=100;`
>
> `dy=zeros(n+2,1);`
>
> `for j=2:n`
>
> `dy1=5*(n+1)*(y(1)+sum(y(j)))-n*y(1);`
>
> `dy(j)=n*y(j-1)-n*y(j);`
>
> `dy3 =-5*(n+1)*(y(1)+sum(y(j)));`
>
> `dy4 =n*y(n);`
>
> `dy=[dy1;dy(j);dy3;dy4];`
>
> `end`

Why is this giving me a vector of length 4? I want a vector of lenth n+2.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Please do check how to properly write mathematics in this site with LaTeX-MathJax.

Comment: The spacebar is you friend. You really need to properly space and indent your code to make it readable by others. One of your lines has 36 characters in a row without a single space between them. Imaginetryingtoreadwhatothershavewrittenwithoutusingspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you want the code to do. My best understanding is that `dy1` is to be in position $1$, `dy3` in position $n+1$, `dy4` in position $n+2$ and positions $2-n$ are calculated using the loop. This can be corrected as follows.

It makes no sense to use `sum(y(j))` as this is summing a single element. I have changed this to be `sum(y)` which adds the elements of `y`, as I think you meant to do.

Also, if `n` is the length of `y`, they you should use `n=length(y);` instead of hard coding the value.

```
function dy = SIR(t,y)

n = 100;

dy = zeros(n+2,1);

tempVal = 5*(n+1)*( y(1) + sum(y) );

dy(1) = tempVal - n*y(1);
for j=2:n
    dy(j) = n*( y(j-1) - y(j) );
end
dy(n+1) = -tempVal;
dy(n+2) = n*y(n);
```

Comment: Thank you daryl and danyule. I'm sorry my question isn't very clear but i'm new to matlab and don't really understand properly. But thank you, your answers are very helpful!

Comment: @Jane Smith if you found either of our answers helpful, you should up vote them when you have enough reputation. There is also the option to mark an answer as accepted, which is the one that you choose that answers your question best in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The line `dy=[dy1;dy(j);dy3;dy4];` is within your for-loop and assigns `dy` to a $4 \times 1$ vector.